# WordPress just for Backend

Tags: rest-api

Does it make any sense to use a WordPress site just to feed an external website?

I already have a website with a lot of content. I've copied all the content to WordPress.

I would like the original site to read the content via REST API from the WordPress copy and use it as the administration area for the old site.

What do you think about it?

Comment: You should look into the idea of headless WordPress.

Comment: Well, basically that is my idea, is it already something used?

Comment: Yep.  Used A LOT.

Comment: Like A LOT A LOT.  WordPress' robust content management is really user friendly and a lot of large companies find that it's relatively simple to hire qualified content and marketing staff who already have experience with WP - but, for any number of reasons, they don't want their front end powered by WP. So they use the REST API for their headless WP which is coded up using React or any other number of platforms. Gatsby is a popular one, https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary/headless-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a try

Comment: Thanks @TonyDjukic for formatting my question and for the link to Gatsby.
Do you know any good reference about wordpress setting too?
I mean, I already have a framework to feed, so front end is covered already, but I would like to know if the is any document about good practices for setting up a wordpress headless backend

Comment: Your best bet would be to look through the documentation for Gatsby.  I suspect different frameworks have different requirements, so I don't think it's a single answer.